# How can I create session in Amadeus web service

Tags: wsdl, amadeus

I am new in Amadeus web service integration; I use a wsdl from below address:
https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/xxxxxxx
this web service contains below methods:

```
•   Air_MultiAvailability
•   Air_SellFromRecommendation
•   DocIssuance_IssueTicket
•   Fare_CheckRules
•   Fare_InformativePricingWithoutPNR
•   Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch
•   Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass
•   Fare_PricePNRWithLowerFares
•   PNR_AddMultiElements
•   PNR_Retrieve
•   PNR_Retrieve2
•   Queue_PlacePNR
•   Security_SignOut
•   Ticket_CreateTSTFromPricing
```

But there is no method to get Security token. Do you know how can I get security token code and login to web service?

Comment: Im struck with this.. did you get any update or how did you solve.. Please help

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian - Did u find a way to get Session Id and Security Token ?? Because Im stuck with it now.. :/

Answer (score 2):

WSDL in Amadeus environment are created in a portal, you need to ask the WSAP admin of your organization to add the Security_Authenticate definition to your WSDL.

The authentication is made using an OfficeId, Username and password.